# AWS EC2 CLI How to get list EC2 Instances - limit output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need to limit the output by fields - just need: Instance-type, Name, Instance ID, Public-Ip-address, Pvt-IPAddress.

I try `aws ec2 describe-instances --output text`  - this gives me lot more fields than I need.

I dont need any 'filters' to limit but just get the limited fields I need. Output can be text or tabular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and constraint seem confusing, but you are mixing `query` with `filter`.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output table --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress]'
```

This will list instances but limit the field to `[InstanceId,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress]`

`--query` is the list of fields that you want to be returned in the response. This is kind of **client-side**, you get all but you just want to get some field from the response as per your need.

`--filter` is the condition used to select which resources you want to be described, this is kind of **server-side**, the command return selected resources.

[introduction-to-the-aws-cli](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/dev323introduction-to-the-aws-cli)

Comment: **This worked**, so need names without hyphens - the CLI reference lists them with hyphen. Not sure why we need Reservations[*] - but tried without it it does not work. My issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `--query` option to [limit the output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html).

Comment: query looks like filter - could you elaborate with example

Comment: @Sam-T did you look at the examples in the documentation I linked to?

Comment: I ran this - *get error*:    '$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --query 'EC2[*].[ip-address,instance-type]' --output table

Bad value for --query EC2[*].[ip-address,instance-type]: Bad jmespath expression: Unknown token '-': EC2[*].[ip-address,instance-type]'